# Clear state from Parent with a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have two `class` based components.

Parent Component: **App**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        search: ''
    }

    getSearchFromSearchBar = (searchBarData) => {
        this.setState({ search: searchBarData })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                <div className='section'>
                    <div className='container'>
                        <h1 className='title has-text-weight-light is-size-2' style={{ fontFamily: 'Bungee' }}>Search a video</h1>
                        <SearchBar onUserClick={this.getSearchFromSearchBar} search={this.state.search} />
                        <p>
                            Parent: {this.state.search}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default App;
```

Child Component: **SearchBar**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {
    state = {
        search: ''
    }

    handleClick = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.onUserClick(this.state.search)
    }

    getUserInput = async (event) => {
        this.setState({ search: event.target.value })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='field has-addons'>
                    <div className='control has-icons-left is-expanded'>
                        <input className="input is-medium" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.getUserInput} id="search" type="text"></input>
                        <span className="icon is-small is-left">
                            <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <p className='control'>
                        <button className={`button is-info is-medium`} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            <span className={`icon`}>
                                <i className='fas fa-search'></i>
                            </span>
                            <span style={{ fontFamily: 'Bungee' }}>
                                Search
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                    <p className='control'>
                        <button className={`button is-danger is-medium`} onClick={() => this.setState({ search: '' })}>
                            <span className={`icon`}>
                                <i className='fas fa-search'></i>
                            </span>
                            <span style={{ fontFamily: 'Bungee' }}>
                                Clear
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default SearchBar;
```

I'm trying to clear the `state` from the parent component when the user clicks on the `clear` button. I'm having a hard time doing this because I cannot send arguments when invoking this.handleClick on JSX. Is there a workaround to this?

I also am managing two states, is this the right approach? I tried using props but I cannot modify them since its a read only property.

Comment: Indeed you can do pass the arguments , please check this https://dev.to/spukas/moving-arguments-from-child-to-parent-component-in-react-25lp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay having two states. The state in your child maintains the text in the input. The state in your parent is the actual term the user searched for right? I'd name them different things so it's clear that they have different purposes, such as `searchedTerm` in the parent vs `value` in the child or something like that. One changes on every keyboard click (the value in the child displayed in the input), the other state is the actual term the user wants to search (after clicking).

You can absolutely pass arguments to the function.

```
<button className={`button is-info is-medium`} onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.state.search)}>
```

Notice I'm returning a function.... which calls the function you passed down in props. This isn't necessary for you as your function takes an event and already does this.

Now... you mentioned you want to clear the state in the parent component, I'm not sure why you'd want to send an argument, but you'd simply pass down a function to the child. the child would have a prop called `clearClicked` and the child would run that when the button was clicked.

Child:

```
 <button className={`button is-danger is-medium`} onClick={() => { 
   this.setState({ search: '' });
   clearClicked(); // the function passed down as a prop
  }
 >
```

Parent:

```
  <SearchBar onUserClick={this.getSearchFromSearchBar} 
    search={this.state.search} 
    clearClicked={() => this.setState({ search: '' })} 
  />
```

Comment: What about clearing the state from the parent directly from the child, when the user clicks the "clear" button.

Comment: Edited for that. Also had a typo.

Comment: Thank you so much, I cleared the child state with this.setState({search: ''}) and the parent state with the callback function pass through props.
--------
<button className={`button is-danger is-medium`} ref={this.buttonActionRef} onClick={() => { this.setState({ search: '' }); this.props.onUserClick('') }}>

Comment: No problem, please mark this as accepted if it worked for you, and if you have any more questions feel free to comment here, I'll be glad to help (or link to a new question)